# Serializing an object to JSON, XML, YAML?

Tags: ruby, xml, json, serialization, yaml

I asked a previous question about serialization and validation. Someone mentioned using the JSON gem which allows me to tell my object how to serialize with the `to_json` method, however Ruby seems to do LOTS of complicated things really easily, however on the flip side some really simple things seem to be quite complicated, Serialization being one of those things.

I want to find out if there is a way to have a clean object:

```
class CleanClass
    attr_accessor :variable1
    attr_accessor :variable2
    attr_accessor :variable3
end

cleanObject = CleanClass.new
```

Ideally, I don't want to dirty the model, I just want to pass it to *something* and tell it what the output type should be and let it work its magic.

An example would be something like:

```
jsonOutput = MagicSerializer::Json.Serialize(cleanObject)
xmlOutput = MagicSerializer::Xml.Serialize(cleanObject)
yamlOutput = MagicSerializer::Yaml.Serialize(cleanObject)

revertedJsonObject = MagicSerializer::Json.Unserialize(jsonOutput)
revertedXmlObject = MagicSerializer::Xml.Unserialize(xmlOutput)
revertedYamlObject = MagicSerializer::Yaml.Unserialize(yamlOutput)
```

I want to pass something an object, and get the strings outputted, then be able to convert it back.

I know ActiveModel has serialization functionality but I need to dirty my class to do this, and I don't want to change the model if possible. ActiveSupport seems to satisfy the JSON criteria as I can just call that and it will take an object and spit out the JSON, but I would like to support other types.

Any further information would be great!

Comment: `JSON.dump(object)` and `JSON.parse(string)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ruby has built-in automagical serialization/deserialization to binary and yaml.

Yaml:

```
require 'yaml'
serialized = CleanClass.new.to_yaml
object = YAML.load(serialized)
```

Marshal:

```
serialized = Marshal.dump(CleanClass.new)
object = Marshal.load(serialized)
```

Comment: Yep, I have seen these, but Json is most important currently for me, then Xml, then Yaml. So I was hoping there would be a gem or library that does everything from on simplified interface.

Comment: The JSON format is too limited to capture the state of an entire ruby object. It only has primitives, so you would need to customize your JSON to include type information of the instance variables. Furthermore, if the goal is serialization so the object can be read back somewhere else, you would probably need to adhere to an API. You could say a class's responsibility is converting itself to an external format, and reading that format back in.

Comment: Like I said in the response to Dave above, I dont see why you need to tell ruby how to serialize these classes (using the assumptions above). All they really need is a recursive method to go through each instance of an object, until they reach another object, then go down further into the tree, I am sure all objects end up as a model of simple types at the end. The only time I could see the user needing to input any serialization logic themselves is if they want to change the name of the keys, i.e attr_accessor :Surname to be serialized to lastname or something similar.

Comment: First, you don't want only the "public" instance variables to be serialized. If you need to construct the object back, you also need the private variables. Second, there's no such thing as public instance variables. attr_accessor is actually just defining a getter and a setter for the always-private instance variables. What you want could be done, but it is not trivial and I don't see why you would need it anyway. If you don't care about the serialization format, just use YAML for portable output or Marshal. If you do care, use something like ActiveModel.

Comment: Sorry if I was vauge, I want to adhere to a standard, be it Json, Yaml, Xml. I however want an object agnostic of either of them to be converted into and back out of the said format. I thought Ruby still had the idea of public and private, just expressed it differently, either way i will rephrase, I would assume only variables be serialized, methods and constants needn't be. Doesn't every ruby object have an instance_variables method which gives you an array of  every variable, with that array you can serialize and unserialize using instance_variable_get/instance_variable_set.

Comment: Just to give some reasoning to the previous comment, imagine you have a web service that consumed by many different platforms. Some people want to communicate with xml, others with json, and some with yaml. The server which exposes and consumes data should have a contract model of some sort, agnostic of how its going out and coming in, so if you start making concessions for one format you will have to do it for them all. So thats why I want my model to be agnostic of the way it is being exposed

Comment: As far as I know, this has not been implemented for JSON. Some googling shows it does exist for XML, although the project is dated. http://clabs.org/clxmlserial.htm. My recommendation remains: use YAML unless you have a very good reason not to.

Comment: If you are using it for a web service, use ActiveModel's serialization. Each serialization format has its own specifics and you cannot always deal with them in a transparant way. The YAML serialization or XML serialization I mentioned previously are only useful when you need to store data for your application to come back to later, not for API communication.

Comment: I wouldn't entirely agree with your last comment, if you are using a SOAP web service or something that needs to know about all types up front then yeah ok. However with RESTful style interfaces where there it is just simple models being passed to and forth without any formal interfaces it is ideal. Anyway it looks like the answer to my question is no, there isnt any libraries to do this for you without having to write your own serialization configuration logic. So will give you the answer for your additional information and justifications on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

For JSON and YAML it seems pretty easy, since they would only be wrappers for the `to_yaml` and `to_json` methods (or `YAML.load` and `from_json` respectively)

For JSON you would have to wrap own classes around core-Types (or other types which implement to_json) e.g. first implement a to_hash method which then can be transformed into json.

XML is much more complicated because of the hierarchy-aspect, you'd have to standardize it,
but actually i don't understand from your explanation what is wrong with the basic `to_...` methods. This is actually the convention we use in Ruby. If you're concerned with pollution of models, you could put these methods in a module, and include the module in the class.

```
module Foo
  def to_serialized_type
   ...
  end
end
class CleanClass
  include Foo
end
```

Comment: When you are trying to use to_xxxx with an instance of one of your own classes you have to write a to_xxxx method within your class to tell it how to serialize (from what I have currently read, or it comes out like #<9135f3> instead of {something:blah}). That is the problem I dont want to have to pollute the model with serialization concerns.

Comment: i wouldn't call it polluting, since that is kind of the way you work normally in ruby: directly on the object instead of functionally

Answer (score 1):

Have your magic serialization method dirty the object for you; the emdirtering can happen on a per-object basis.

Or dirty at your class level.

Either way, your mainline code doesn't see it.

Comment: Could you elaborate more, I kinda know you can add to classes after the declaration, which is maybe what you mean. However even if I wrote some code outside of that class to tell it how to serialize, thats more code I have to maintain within my project, and would have to be written per class type. i.e if a Person class has a firstname and surname, then a business class has name, address fields then you would need to write 2 separate bits of serialization logic to deal with them, with complex object graphs this would begin to become unmaintainable.

Comment: Existing serialization code isn't told how to write out an object, at least for simple properties, it interrogates the object. If you have complex serialization needs you'll have to tell it how /somewhere/. You're basically asking for two things: I want complete control of how my class serialized, but I don't want that information in my class, and I want it handled automatically. It doesn't work like that-you need to define how it will be serialized /somewhere/.

Comment: Let me just clarify, I am not asking for complete control of how my class is serialized. I just want it serialized, the following assumptions can be made of any class that is auto serialized without any effort on the users part. Only publicly accessible fields/vars are serialized, and they are used as a key value pair UNLESS the value is another class, in which you use recursion to keep going down the tree until all simple types have been serialized. I think they are fair assumptions and (although I dont know ruby that well) should be easy enough to get access to.

Comment: What happens when your object has a reference to itself as an attribute, or a reference to another object which in turn contains a reference back to your object as one of its attributes? Or any other kind of cyclic references for that matter.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be serializing it... just joking, Let me just clarify, I am NOT AGAINST people manually configuring certain aspects of how to serialize their objects. I just think that a good deal if not all of common scenarios can be auto serialized. I didn't want to bring other languages into this, but coming from .net I can easily serialize models to json, xml, binary or pretty much any other format, Java is pretty much the same and im sure Python is able to do the sort of thing I am talking about, but I think they call it pickling. I just think that 99% of serialization needs are simple